# how do i convert the date to IST using date and strtotime function in php

Tags: php

i am using a timestamp to store the current date in the database. here is what i am using.

```
 $date = date("dFY");
 $timestamp = strtotime($date);
```

now the above code fetches the current date from the server which is hosted in U.S, whereas i would like it to store the date according to Indian time which is GMT : +05:30 , how do i make sure it insert the current date according to indian time (IST).

here is the link to the date() in PHP.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

although it says i have to use the parameter O with +0530, i am unsure on how do i use it. please help me out on this.

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `O` parameter for `date` is for displaying the timezone difference, not for setting it.

You can set your timezone using: `date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta');`

Also, you should be aware that you're only creating a `datestamp`, not a `timestamp`. It will stay the same for the entire day. If you want an actual `timestamp`, this should suffice:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta');
$timestamp = time();
```

Answer (score 1):

how about this

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('GMT');
$temp= strtotime("+5 hours 30 minutes"); 
$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",$temp);
echo $date
?>
```